# Is it possible to automatically load an implicit def if included as a dependency (no importing)

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm working on a commons library that includes a config library (https://github.com/kxbmap/configs).
This config library uses "kebab-case" when parsing configuration files by default and it can be overridden by an implicit def in scope.

However, I don't want to force that on the users of my commons library when they get access to the config library transitively.

So without me forcing users to import this implicit, like:

```
import CommonsConfig._
```

can I somehow override the naming strategy via an implicit that gets into scope by only including my commons library on the classpath. I'm guessing no but I just have to ask :)

So if not, is someone aware of another approach?

kxbmap/configs isn't that well documented to explain this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Implicits work in compile time, so they cannot get magically present if something is included and then disappear if it isn't.

The closest thing would be something like:

- main library

  ```
  package my.library

  // classes, traits, objects but no package object
  ```
- extension

  ```
  package my
  package object library {
    // implicits
  }
  ```
- user's code

  ```
  import my.library._
  ```

however that would only work if there were no package object in main library, only one extension library could pull off this trick at once (Scala doesn't like more than one package object) and user would have to import everything available with a package, always.

In theory you could create a wrapper around all you deps, with your own configs:

```
final case class MyLibConfig(configsCfg: DerivationConfig)
object MyLibConfig {

  implicit val default: MyLibConfig = ...
}
```

and then derive using this wrapper

```
def parseThings(args...)(implicit myLibConfig: MyLibConfig) = {
  implicit val config: DerivationConfig = myLibConfig.config 
  // derivation
}
```

but in practice it would not work (`parseThings` would have to already know the target type or would need to have the already derived implicits passed). Unless you are up to writing your own derivation methods... avoid it.

Some way of making user just import all relevant stuff is the most maintainable strategy. E.g. you could pull off the same thing authors did and add [type aliases for all types that you use](https://github.com/kxbmap/configs/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/configs/package.scala), do the same for companion objects and finally put some implicits there:

```
package my
package object library {

  type MyType = some.library.Type
  val MyType = some.library.Type

  implicit val derivationConfig: DerivationConfig = ...
}
```